# How can I leave out the numbering for certain list levels in a multilevel list?

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting

I am using a multilevel list for automatic indentation, formatting and numbering of a Word document. Currently, my formatting looks similar to this:

```
1 Heading
  1.1 Subheading
    1.1.1 Paragraph
    1.1.2 Paragraph
  1.2 Subheading
    1.2.1 Paragraph
    1.2.2 Paragraph
2 Heading
  2.1 Subheading
    2.1.1 Paragraph
    2.1.2 Paragraph
```

The numbering itself works well, but I don't want the numbering in front of the headers and subheaders. I just want the paragraphs to be numbered, while still taking the current heading/subheading into account, similar to this:

```
Heading
  Subheading
    1.1.1 Paragraph
    1.1.2 Paragraph
  Subheading
    1.2.1 Paragraph
    1.2.2 Paragraph
Heading
  Subheading
    2.1.1 Paragraph
    2.1.2 Paragraph
```

It seems like this is impossible to do with multilevel lists, since removing the numbering from a list level also removes it from all subsequent levels.

Is there another way to achieve this while still leaving the formatting (indentation etc.) intact?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

*Not impossible, but a bit tricky.*

### You want to format the numbering in your first two levels as hidden text.

This is done using the Define New MultiLevel List dialog with each level being attached to an existing Style. Follow the directions in general that are set forth in [Word MVP Shauna Kelly's instructions](http://www.shaunakelly.com/word/numbering/numbering20072010.html). You would need to adjust the indents as well.

[image]

The Indents are not adjusted in this document, yet, just the numbering.

[image: screenshot]

Here is a [temporary link to the document in the last screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/bjnpduvuryqiv5o/deleteme%20numbering%202021-12-27.docx?dl=0).